# How to create an array of methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def id_attachment_require_upload?
    !object.id_attachment?
end

...

def work_attachment_require_upload?
    !object.work_attachment?
end
```

I want to make it like below.

```
array = %w(id address work)
array.each do |a|
    def #{a}_attachment_require_upload?
        !object.#{a}_attachment?
    end
end
```

Is there any way for me to create a array of methods automatically in rails to save me from the redundant work.

Comment: Why don't you create a simpler method that receives a parameter?

Comment: @MaxWilliams when I was starting out with Ruby, i don't have any idea about `define_method` or what you call dynamically creating methods like that (metaprogramming) and English isn't my first language so I find it hard to google stuff like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arup's answer looks like it's the way to go but I'm not sure if `object.#{a}_attachment?` will work.  If it does, then I learned something new today.  You can also use `public_send`.

```
array = %w[id address work]
array.each do |a|
  define_method "#{a}_attachment_require_upload?" do
    !object.public_send("#{a}_attachment?")
  end
end
```

Comment: No dude. without `""` it wouldn't work... sorry that I overlooked.. Thanks for mentioning it..

Answer (score 3):

```
array = %w(id address work)
array.each do |a|
  define_method "#{a}_attachment_require_upload?" do
    !object.public_send("#{a}_attachment?")
  end
end
```